# Why is my html dropdown and button not clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a select and button here but they are not clickable: http://wp12190683.server-he.ch/webcam/test/

The content is generated dynamically via jQuery in lightgallery. The code generated is

```
<div class="demand">
   <select name="picture" class="form-field">
       <option value="baenkli">Bänkli</option>
       <option value="bort">Bort</option>
       <option value="Toissa">Toissa</option>
       <option value="cheminee">Cheminée</option>
   </select>
   <a href="#" class="myButton">Bild abrufen</a>
</div>
```

Why is this? Are the elements behind some others or is it not possible to use such elements created dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `.lg-inner` element which contains the gallery images is full screen on overlaps this element.

You could set the `z-index` of the `.demand` element to `1060` so that it will show above the image. (*but it will overlap the image when required*)